# iOS. How Do I Continuously Pan Across a series of Views?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I have a grid of thumbnails each of which is a UIView. Each thumbnail has a pan gesture attached. If a pan gesture begins on one thumbnail, subsequent thumbnails do not acknowledge the pan gesture even though my finger is indeed moving across them. How do I get all thumbnails to react to a pan gesture even if the gesture did not initiate in the thumbnail?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Have you thought of using the provided [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you're trying to do is basically scrolling through a 2d array of thumbnails?  If that's the case, try putting your thumbnails into a UIScrollView.  This should take care of panning through pictures.  Then put UITapGestureRecognizers in each individual thumbnail if you want to perform some action upon tapping a thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the pan gesture to the superview, and use hitTest:inPoint: to determine which thumbnail the gesture is moving through.